# clojure - access element of 2d vector

Tags: clojure

if I have a 2d vector like this:

```
[[1 2] [3 4] [5 6]]
```

Is this the best way to access an element at a co-ordinate [0, 0]

```
(get (get v 0) 0)
```

Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`get-in`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/get-in) to access a nested structure:

```
(get-in v [0 0]) ; => 1
```

Answer (score 2):

`get-in` works as advertised but it destructuring can work as well.

```
(def v [[1 2] [3 4] [5 6]])
(let [[[a b][c d][e f]] v]
    a)
```